# JSP make http get request and get json response

Tags: json, http, jsp, request, response

I would like to make a http get request which gets a json response. In that session response I would like to store a value into my session. How is this achievable?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Here is the sample code. You'll have response in recvbuff.

```
<%@page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@page import="java.net.*" %>

<%
   String recv;
   String recvbuff;
   URL jsonpage = new URL("http://www.yoursite.com/jsonresponse");
   URLConnection urlcon = jsonpage.openConnection();
   BufferedReader buffread = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlcon.getInputStream()));

   while ((recv = buffread.readLine()) != null)
    recvbuff += recv;
   buffread.close();

   System.out.println(recvbuff);
%>
```

Comment: Simply use the button "{}" it will indent all the selected zone and will appear as code.

Comment: did that, but as it contains <% tags, (I think) my code disappeared in previw. Maybe I was doing something wrong...

Comment: And what is dest here? Is it meant to be jsonpage? Thanks for the help

Comment: Shouldn't the `URLConnection` part and the `BufferedReader` part be surrounded in the try-catch block ?