# Adding request headers to a HTTP call in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, http-headers

I needed to make a HTTP GET request with some additional header parameters from my JSP and I stumbled upon this solution [JSP make http get request and get json response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185559/jsp-make-http-get-request-and-get-json-response) which solved most of my problem. I am able to make the HTTP call from inside the JSP but I am trying to add a couple of authentication fields to the request header for the URL and I am unable to figure out how to.

```
<%@page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@page import="java.net.*" %>

<%
 String recv;
 String recvbuff;
 URL jsonpage = new URL("http://www.yoursite.com/jsonresponse");
 URLConnection urlcon = jsonpage.openConnection();
 BufferedReader buffread = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlcon.getInputStream()));

 while ((recv = buffread.readLine()) != null)
 recvbuff += recv;
 buffread.close();

 System.out.println(recvbuff);
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe adding a **RequestProperty** is what you are looking for.

```
urlcon.addRequestProperty("key","value");
```

[JavaDocs URLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))