# How to use REST Api in JSP?

Tags: javascript, java, rest, jsp

I have a textbox in `JSP` file. When user enters the postcode in the textbox it should go the url of the api and bring the necessary data as required.

`REST Api` is ready and everything is set. I just want to know how should i send my request to the url.

Comment: Do you want that to be done from the browser so it is done interactively, or on the server?

Comment: On the server @ErwinBolwidt

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14185607/7113238 might help.

Comment: If the requirement is to do the rest call on the server side, a tag rest-client tag library can help https://metamug.com/article/jsp/calling-rest-api-from-jsp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, you have a text box in a view(which is being rendered using a JSP template). As soon as the user enters the postal code in the text box, you want to make an request to a server and fetch data.

This can be done using an AJAX call with javascript in the frontend (I'm using jquery here to simplify things). Put this in between  tags in the JSP:

```
BASE_URL = "http://server_url/" // Your REST interface URL goes here

$(".postcode-input button").click(function () {
    var postcode = $(this).parents(".postcode-input")
        .children("input").val();
    // First do some basic validation of the postcode like
    // correct format etc.
    if (!validatePostcode(postcode)) {
        alert("Invalid Postal Code, please try again");
        return false;
    }
    var finalUrl = BASE_URL += "?postcode=" + postcode; 
    $.ajax({
        url: finalUrl,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            // Parse the recieved data here.
            console.log(html);
        }
    });
});
```

Use an input element like this:

```
<div class="postcode-input">
    <input type="text" maxlength="6">
    <button type="submit"></button>
</div>
```

The above code sends a GET request, you can similarly send a POST request. Have a look at the [jQuery AJAX docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more info.